# Querying a large (>5000 objects) Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am working on being able to do an ldapsearch on a very large Active Directory that keeps track of over 5000 members. The problem is that the ldapsearch I use to query the members only returns 1500 members at a time (members 0-1499, I could look at the next 1500 by changing the member;range).

I am using this command

```
ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -x -H ldaps://${ADSERVER}:3269 
           -E pr=10000000/noprompt -D "${BINDDN}" 
           -b "${SEARCHBASE}" '(&(cn=oit-neo-general-campus-vpn)(objectclass=group))' 'member;range=0-*' 
           -w ${BINDPASS} | awk '{print $2}'
```

Is there a way around the 1500 limit? If not, will a script parsing through 1500 members at a time work?

My end goal is to be able to query this very large directory in order to compare it with a group on grouper so I may fix any differences between the two

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is single ldapsearch method that all members can be retrieved.
You will have to iteratively make the call.

In the later versions of Microsoft Active Directory, the [MaxValRange](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/MaxValRange) is fixed at 1,500 and can not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

The max values you can return from an AD is 1500. You have to paginate the query.